# How to filter a column based on values of another column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to build a new column in my existing table.
So there are two columns, 
'cmg' and 'effdate' and I need to create a new column called 'enddate'.
So for a particular cmg, 
the max of eff_date = current date 
and the dates in next row should be equal to the date in the previous row - 1.

For example,

```
cmg |  effdate
1      23/10/2018
1      1/10/2018
1      1/1/2018
3      1/12/2018
3      1/3/2018
```

I need to 1st filter the rows based on the values in cmg column and then get enddate as below:

```
cmg |  effdate   |      enddate  
1      23/10/2018       currentdate 
1      1/10/2018        22/10/2018
1      1/1/2018         30/9/2018
3      1/12/2018        currentdate
3      1/3/2018         30/11/2018
```

Comment: Where did the date `23/10/2018 ` come from in your expected results? It's not in your sample data. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, there were some mistakes in my question.
I have edited the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (cmg INT, effdate DATE)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES
(1,'2018-10-23'),
(1,'2018-10-01'),
(1,'2018-01-01'),
(3,'2019-03-01'),
(3,'2018-12-01')

SELECT cmg, effdate, LAG(DATEADD(DAY,-1,effdate),1, GETDATE()) OVER (PARTITION BY cmg ORDER BY effdate DESC) as enddate
FROM #temp
ORDER BY cmg, effdate DESC
```

The result is as below,

```
cmg  effdate     enddate
1    2018-10-23  2019-06-11
1    2018-10-01  2018-10-22
1    2018-01-01  2018-09-30
3    2019-03-01  2019-06-11
3    2018-12-01  2019-02-28
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LEAD and OVER

```
SELECT cmg, effdate, LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, -1, effdate),1, getdate()) OVER (PARTITION BY cmg ORDER BY effdate ASC) as enddate
FROM testcmg
ORDER BY cmg, effdate DESC
```